# Как оформить список?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет!есть три списка с классом .list, нужно в первом и втором отрисовать красные картинки с крестиком у пункта,подскажите как оформить лучше?какие селекторы  комбинировать?

Comment: в чем проблема? что значит "как оформить лучше?какие селекторы комбинировать?"... есть макет - оформляйте как на нем. Крести каритнками вставьте..svg или jpg решение за вами

Answer (score 0):

```css
.zero{width:15%;background:white;box-shadow:4px 3px 3px #666666;}
.two::before{content: "✔";padding-right: 4px;color:#739bff;border: 1px solid #739bff;border-radius: 20px;height: 4px;padding-left: 4px;padding-top: 4px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 1px;padding-top: 3px;}
.three::before{content:"✔";color:#739bff;padding-right: 4px;border: 1px solid #739bff;border-radius: 20px;height: 4px;padding-left: 4px;padding-top: 3px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 1px;}
.four::before{content:"✖";padding-right: 4px;border: 1px solid #f8558c;border-radius: 20px;height: 4px;padding-left: 4px;padding-top: 3px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 1px;color:#f8558c;}
.five::before{content:"✖";padding-right: 4px;border: 1px solid #f8558c;border-radius: 20px;height: 4px;padding-left: 4px;padding-top: 3px;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 1px;color:#f8558c;}



.two, .three, .four, .five{padding-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<div class="zero">
<div class="two">Lorem</div>
<div class="three">Lorem</div>
<div class="four">Lorem</div>
<div class="five">Lorem</div>
</div>
```